# Showing the object xyz axis lines via python when moving an object

Tags: python, mesh, transforms

In Python selecting an object does not display the axis lines, `bpy.data.objects['Cube'].x = 5` simply moves the object.

I've tried injecting keystrokes like  <kbd>G</kbd>  + <kbd>X</kbd> after object is selected but didn't succeed. Is there a way to display these axis guidelines via Python ?

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you’re talking about the move gizmo? Everything stated seems to be expected behavior.

Comment: If you want to permanently show an object's axis, you can use `bpy.context.object.show_axis = True`. It's in Properties Editor > Object tab > Viewport Display > Axis.